# Mongoose unable to save or persist to database with a POST Request; gives no error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to send data through Postman to a REST API made of Node.js and Mongoose

[image]

I am getting the following response :

[image]

but this does not persist or save to Mongo DB :

[image]

I added the following :

```
mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    console.log(`${collectionName}.${method}`, JSON.stringify(query), doc);
});
```

so I am also getting this at the console **(is session supposed to be null)?**:

```
standups.insertOne {"_id":"5f9e54cea6d454065f0a963b","teamMember":"Mark","project":"Trinity Web Application","workYesterday":"Build out the Models","workToday":"Testing the API Endpoint using Postman","impediment":"None","createdOn":"2020-10-31T22:30:03.000Z","__v":0} { session: null }
```

I have configured with the following files at my server backend :

**api/routes/standup.js**

```
const Standup = require('../../models/standup')

module.exports = function (router) {
    // GET: the 12 newest stand-up meeting notes
    router.get('/standup', function (req, res) {

    })

    // POST: Get new meeting note document...
    router.post('/standup', async function (req, res) {
        let note = new Standup(req.body)
        await note.save(function (err, note) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json(err)
            }
            res.status(200).json(note)
        })
    })
}
```

**api/models/standup.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const standupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    teamMember: { type: String },
    project: { type: String },
    workYesterday: { type: String },
    workToday: { type: String },
    impediment: { type: String },
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}, { bufferCommands: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Standup', standupSchema)
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const api = require('./api')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8081

app.set('port', port)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api', api)
app.use(express.static('static'))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(function (req,res) {
    const err = new Error('Not Found')
    err.status = 404
    res.json(err)
})

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/virtualstandups', {useNewUrlParser: true, bufferCommands: false})
mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    console.log(`${collectionName}.${method}`, JSON.stringify(query), doc);
});

const db = mongoose.connection

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '))
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')    
    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('API Server Listening on port ' +  app.get('port') + '!')
    })
})
```

Backend does return original object; however does not persist and sends no error. I am using MongoDB and Node through WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was

1. I installed Mongo DB as a service on windows
2. I installed mongodb on WSL2 / Ubuntu at a different time ( I forgot I already installed on windows)

Both using the same port 27107

Using Mongo DB Compass, I can only see the Windows MongoDB which yielded no changes; but data was actually getting sent to the WSL2/Ubuntu MongoDB.

Solution :

Uninstall MongoDB on Windows or run MongoDB in only one platform.